# Extract data with Selenium - how to locate element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I got a HTML code as below:

```
<a class="msgIdentityText" href="http://test.com" id="ext-comp-1015">NAME1, NAME2, NAME3</a>
```

I need to extract NAME1 and insert it onto a variable in my Python script. What is the best way to do this? I have tried:

```
k = driver.find_element_by_class_name("msgIdentityText").get_attribute('id')
k = driver.find_element_by_id("ext-comp-1015").get_attribute('name')
```

Can someone help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you want to do is get `NAME1, NAME2, NAME3` text into a variable, that variable would be `data` below

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="ext-comp-1015"]')
data = elem.text
```

Then you need to take that `data` string, and split it so you can get whichever piece of it you want.

```
data = 'NAME1, NAME2, NAME3' # hardcoded just for example purposes 
result = [x.strip() for x in data.split(',')]
new_variable = result[0]
print(new_variable)
```

Prints:

```
NAME1
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this without use xpath? It is variable.

Comment: Yea you can use whatever find method you want, the important piece is the 2nd part where I show you how to split the resulting variable text

Comment: Great! Thank you :) You helped me a lot.

Comment: Oneliner:

    k = driver.find_element_by_class_name("msgIdentityText").text.split(',')[0]